# Sharing PYTHONPATH among team

Tags: python, pythonpath, pipenv

I'm at a company where currently to run our local dev envs, we run a shell script that exports a bunch of variables, including a PYTHONPATH addition (with the main content being in a subfolder).

In a few weeks, I'll be moving us over to pipenv, and I know one of it's advantages is being able to automatically include a `.env`. However, I know I can't use that to add onto a preexisting env var (or if I can, I don't know the correct syntax for that), so I'm unsure how we can better setup our environments. Seems like a hassle to have to run a shell script so that you can run your environment. And if you change projects, you need to run a different shell script?

How can our team best manage stuff like our PYTHONPATH? Or is it something we should setup in our IDEs and ignore, save for when we run the scripts (like in Docker)?

Comment: Not sure, but you could change your shell script to append (not overwrite) to the local `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable.

Comment: That's currently what happens. But for example, if I move between two different repos and run two different scripts, that means now both are in my `PYTHONPATH` and thus if the wrong one has the reqs, I'd get bad results locally.

Comment: I haven't used `pipenv`, more of a `venv` user myself, but you should be able to execute the project directly with the `python` executable within the project related scripts without switching shells.  E.g. running `./project1/bin/python -m my_module` and `./project2/bin/python -m other_module` should use their respective environment without activation required.

Comment: Depending on how you plan on executing your scripts, it might also be just easier to do the entire set up on IDE as you mentioned.  Otherwise, it might be worthwhile to build your shell script with the full path of respective `python` you wanted to run as per my previous comment.